# Ignore lines from linting and formating - VSC EsLint + Prettier

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, prettier-eslint

```
some.JS.Code;

//ignore this line from linting etc.
##Software will do some stuff here, but for JS it's an Error##

hereGoesJs();
```

Is there a possibility to exlude a line from linting and formatting in Visual Studio Code?
Because I need the line, but also need Linting and Formatting for the other part of the Code...

```
// I Tried

// eslint-disable-next-line no-use-before-define

// eslint-disable-line no-use-before-define

/*eslint-disable */

//suppress all warnings between comments
alert('foo');

/*eslint-enable */

// @ts-ignore
```

Comment: Yes. You should look in the ESLint documentation. It's all explained there.

Comment: @Andy I looked up and tried, but it's not working :/

Comment: Add the specific code to your question, and what you've tried.

Comment: @Andy I added what I've tried

Comment: It was a little confusing for me the first time I  did it too. I wanted to  disable one rule for 8 lines of code, and it took me a couple hours of trying different comments to get it right. Anyhow I am glad my answer helped. +1

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Yes you have a couple of options available to you.

---

##### Option #1 Disabling Specific Rules:

```
  /* eslint-disable no-var */
  
  var x = 'apple sauce'; 
  
  /* eslint-enable no-var */
```

---

##### Option #2 Disabling Entire Files:

```
// Anything up here will still be affected by the linter.

/* eslint-disable */  // Disables everything from this point down
```

---

##### Option #3 Disabling a Single Line:

```
    // eslint-disable-next-line 
    var x = 'apple sauce';
    
    //  or you can do this:

    var y = 'apple sauce'; // eslint-disable-line
```

---

###### The official ESLint page that covers the topic, "Disabling ESLint", is located at the link below

###### https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/rules#disabling-rules